# Error running cardano-db-sync in docker-compose file as devcontainer

Tags: cardano-node, cardano-db-sync

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file which I use as a `devcontainer` for VSCode. Part of my application requires access to `cardano-db-sync` so that I can query the database for transaction information. I am unsure how to get the `dev` service to communicate with the `db-sync` service. I have copied the entire `docker-compose.yml` and `config/` directory from `cardano-db-sync` into my project. The error I'm getting is:

```
Connecting to network: mainnet
/nix/store/6f4mj582ymmn8zx90j8f8n9sx540hi9x-entry-point/bin/entry-point: line 26: /nix/store/74ky2ipmmh6y7qjxp0q03vh316dxddw2-cardano-db-sync-mainnet: Is a directory
/nix/store/6f4mj582ymmn8zx90j8f8n9sx540hi9x-entry-point/bin/entry-point: line 26: exec: /nix/store/74ky2ipmmh6y7qjxp0q03vh316dxddw2-cardano-db-sync-mainnet: cannot execute: Is a directory
/nix/store/6f4mj582ymmn8zx90j8f8n9sx540hi9x-entry-point/bin/entry-point: line 26: /nix/store/74ky2ipmmh6y7qjxp0q03vh316dxddw2-cardano-db-sync-mainnet: Is a directory
/nix/store/6f4mj582ymmn8zx90j8f8n9sx540hi9x-entry-point/bin/entry-point: line 26: exec: /nix/store/74ky2ipmmh6y7qjxp0q03vh316dxddw2-cardano-db-sync-mainnet: cannot execute: Is a directory
```

My `dev` service looks like this:

```
    dev:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: DevContainer.Dockerfile
        volumes: [
            ../:/app/
        ]
        command: sleep infinity
        ports:
            - "3001:3001"
        networks:
            - dev-network
        cap_add:
            - SYS_PTRACE
        security_opt:
            - seccomp:unconfined
```

and `db-sync` is:

```
    cardano-db-sync:
        image: inputoutput/cardano-db-sync:10.0.0
        environment:
            - NETWORK=${NETWORK:-mainnet}
            - POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
        depends_on:
            - cardano-node
            - postgres
        secrets:
            - postgres_password
            - postgres_user
            - postgres_db
        volumes:
            - db-sync-data:/var/lib/cdbsync
            - node-ipc:/node-ipc
        networks:
            - dev-network
        restart: on-failure
        logging:
            driver: "json-file"
            options:
                max-size: "200k"
                max-file: "10"

secrets:
    postgres_db:
        file: ./config/secrets/postgres_db
    postgres_password:
        file: ./config/secrets/postgres_password
    postgres_user:
        file: ./config/secrets/postgres_user

volumes:
    db-sync-data:
    postgres:
    node-db:
    node-ipc:

networks:
    dev-network:
```

Comment: saw this GitHub issue 
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/issues/655

Answer (score 0):

upgrading the image version to 10.0.1 will resolve the entry point issue.

```
image: inputoutput/cardano-db-sync:10.0.1
```

Comment: Really? The comments on the GitHub issue: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/issues/655 say the issue is still unresolved.

Comment: @NikeDattani It was resolved by 10.0.1 release. check the issue again.

Comment: At the time of your answer, the last comment was "This is still an issue as replicated by @meiblorn." It was hours later than the issue was closed (without really answering that last comment).

Comment: @NikeDattani 
I saw this pull request.
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/pull/698